# How to use app navigation with google maps parameters and route

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I don't understand how the `MAP_SCREEN` route parameters are used with Google Maps app in jetpack compose navigation. The parameters are unrecognized in the route. Where do I add the MapsScreen `snackbarHost`, `navController` and `fetchLocationUpdates` parameters? Can you also give me an overview/guide of how jetpack navigation works in this context?

```
composable(MAP_SCREEN) {
            MapsScreen(
                snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState,
                navController = navController,
                fetchLocationUpdates = fetchLocationUpdates
            )
        }
```

Here is my BetteHomesAppState.kt file

```
package com.example.bettehomes
import android.Manifest
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.ReadOnlyComposable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalConfiguration
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilder
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.bettehomes.common.composable.PermissionDialog
import com.example.bettehomes.common.composable.RationaleDialog
import com.example.bettehomes.common.snackbar.SnackbarManager
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.login.LoginScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.settings.SettingsScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.sign_up.SignUpScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.splash.SplashScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.map.MapsScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.map.GeoMarkerScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.map.GeoMarkerViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.theme.BetteHomesTheme
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.ExperimentalPermissionsApi
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.isGranted
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.rememberPermissionState
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.shouldShowRationale
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope



@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
fun BetteHomesApp() {
  BetteHomesTheme {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
      RequestNotificationPermissionDialog()
    }

    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
        val appState = rememberAppState()

      Scaffold(
        snackbarHost = {
          SnackbarHost(
            hostState = it,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            snackbar = { snackbarData ->
              Snackbar(snackbarData, contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary)
            }
          )
        },
        scaffoldState = appState.scaffoldState
      ) { innerPaddingModifier ->
        NavHost(
          navController = appState.navController,
          startDestination = SPLASH_SCREEN,
          modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPaddingModifier)
        ) {
          betteHomesGraph(appState)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun RequestNotificationPermissionDialog() {
  val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)

  if (!permissionState.status.isGranted) {
    if (permissionState.status.shouldShowRationale) RationaleDialog()
    else PermissionDialog { permissionState.launchPermissionRequest() }
  }
}

@Composable
fun rememberAppState(
  scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(),
  snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState = rememberSnackbarHostState(),
  navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
  snackbarManager: SnackbarManager = SnackbarManager,
  resources: Resources = resources(),
  coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
) =
  remember(scaffoldState, navController, snackbarManager, resources, coroutineScope) {
    BetteHomesAppState(scaffoldState, navController, snackbarManager, resources, coroutineScope)
  }

@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
fun resources(): Resources {
  LocalConfiguration.current
  return LocalContext.current.resources
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun NavGraphBuilder.betteHomesGraph(appState: BetteHomesAppState) {
  composable(SPLASH_SCREEN) {
    SplashScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
  }

  composable(SETTINGS_SCREEN) {
    SettingsScreen(
      restartApp = { route -> appState.clearAndNavigate(route) },
      openScreen = { route -> appState.navigate(route) }
    )
  }

  composable(LOGIN_SCREEN) {
    LoginScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
  }

  composable(SIGN_UP_SCREEN) {
    SignUpScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
  }

    composable(MAP_SCREEN) {
        MapsScreen(
            snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState,
            navController = navController,
            fetchLocationUpdates = fetchLocationUpdates
        )
    }
  composable(GEOMARKER_SCREEN) {
    GeoMarkerScreen(geoMarkerViewModel = GeoMarkerViewModel())
  }
```